# Using expect to confirm a password

Tags: bash, expect

What I'm trying to do is write an expect script that backs up all databases on a server, then create an encrypted zip file (I couldn't get my tar/openssl command to run properly in expect) containing the sql file.

**This is just an exercise to learn about expect, not a real backup solution.**

I'm obviously lacking some understanding here. What I want to do is:

- Back up all databases to a file (done)
- Run the zip command to create an encrypted zip file (done... sorta)
- Respond to "Enter password: "
- Then response to the confirmation "Verify password: "

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -f
  exp_internal 1
  set backupdir "/mnt/db-backups/"
  set now [clock seconds]
  set date [clock format $now -format {%Y-%m-%d}]
  set filename $date

  append filename "_dbbackups.sql"

  exec mysqldump -u root --all-databases --events > $backupdir$filename

  spawn zip -e $backupdir$filename.enc.zip $backupdir$filename

  expect {
      "Enter password: " { send "monkey"
      exp_continue
      }
      "Verify password: " {send "monkey"
      exp_continue
      }
  }
  ```

And the output is

```
    $expect encrypt.sh 
    spawn zip -e /mnt/db-backups/2013-12-11_dbbackups.sql.enc.zip /mnt/db-backups/2013-12-11_dbbackups.sql
    parent: waiting for sync byte
    parent: telling child to go ahead
    parent: now unsynchronized from child
    spawn: returns {15733}

    expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Enter password: "? no
    "Verify password: "? no
    Enter password: 
    expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Enter password: "? yes
    expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Enter password: "
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
    expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
    send: sending "monkey" to { exp6 }
    expect: continuing expect

    expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Enter password: "? no
    "Verify password: "? no
    monkey
    expect: does "monkey" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Enter password: "? no
    "Verify password: "? no
    -- then I exited --
```

It's a pretty simple script... but I'm sucking at it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple:

You have to press return. So just change the command

```
send "monkey"
```

to

```
send "monkey\r"
```

(both of them)

Answer (score 0):

Expect is a really ugly and troublesome solution for this.

For the `mysqldump` part, add your database connection information and the password in `~/.my.cnf` following this format:

```
[client]
database=dbname
user=dbuser
password=dbpass
host=dbhost
```

If you work with multiple databases, then you'll have to create one file per database, for example `~/.my.cnf.dbname`, and call `mysqldump` like this:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf.$dbname $dbname | gzip >"$target"
```

Make sure to do `chmod 600` on this file to make it as secure as possible.

And when you encrypt with `openssl`, you can put the password on the command line like this:

```
... | openssl des3 -pass pass:monkey >"$target"
```

You can put this after `gzip` in the earlier command. Of course, use a different cipher instead of `des3` if you want more security. Also, instead of passing the password on the command line, you might want to use `file:pathname` option instead to get the password from the first line of the file instead.

Comment: Thanks Janos. I have something very similar to your solution in place currently (I'm just trying to figure out how to do it with expect to learn a bit about it). Thanks again.

Comment: Learn `expect` when you really need it. Hopefully never.

Answer (score 0):

DRY:

```
spawn zip -e $backupdir$filename.enc.zip $backupdir$filename
expect {
    "* password: " {
        send "monkey\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glenn. I'm using your code from above but it still seems to be failing to match the second request for input. It matches the first "Enter password:" string, but the second "Verify Password:" never shows up in the debugging output.

Comment: I can't seem for format it any better sorry! expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "* password: "? no
Enter password: 
expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "* password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Enter password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
send: sending "monkey\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "* password: "? no
monkey

expect: does "monkey\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "* password: "? no
expect: timed out

Comment: I was helping another user who had just this same problem but using a tool called zipcloak. I don't have any further insight for you.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] write an expect script [...]

Not how I'd do it.

```
  zip -P password [...]
```

Knowing nothing about your Zip version ("zip -v"), it's hard to say
if you simply didn't look at the documentation ("zip -h2", "man zip").
Putting a password into a script is a sufficient security hazard that
"-P" was left undocumented until Zip 3.0 (when the developers got tired
of answering the how-do-I questions).  But putting a password into a
script once can hardly be worse than putting a password into a script
twice.